# Eclipse workspaces and projects vs IntelliJ projects and modules?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, project

Switching to using *IntelliJ* for all my coding but am confused by the use of **'projects'** and **modules** in *IntelliJ*.

Can someone tell me if *Eclipse* **'projects'** is the same as IntelliJ's use of **'project'**.

Or is an *Eclipse* **'workspace'** more like an *IntelliJ* **'project**'?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The JetBrains website has this covered.

[Migrating From Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html)

The quick answer is an Eclipse *Project* is equivalent to an IDEA *Module*. The concept of *Project* in IDEA is like a *Workspace* in Eclipse.

#### Edit:

Also take a look at the [eclipse integration page](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Eclipse_integration#Eclipse_and_IDEA_project_structure_basics).

Comment: Main link is down.

Answer (score 0):

A module is the equivalent of a project in eclipse.

I got the answer from one of JetBrains' short videos they provide on their site. I found them useful when played at 2X speed, so I could get up to speed on the IDE quickly: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA and have come from Eclipse world. I was initially confused by notion of projects and  modules in IntelliJ IDEA . However after viewing this very useful video [Running IntelliJ IDEA for the First Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_jXj0XTwSg&list=PLPZy-hmwOdEXdOtXdFzyx_XCnrF_oD2Ft), my understanding on  has been greatly improved. Basically the projects and modules in  IntelliJ IDEA are equivalent Eclipse workspace and projects. I recommend watching this video if you are new to IntelliJ IDEA